# ModuleNotFoundError while writing unittest in python

Tags: python, python-unittest

This is my project structure

```
   |
   |---------src
   |          |
   |          |---------main.py
   |          |
   |
   |--------test
   |          |
   |          |---------__init__.py
   |          |
              |
              |---------test_main.py
```

This is my simple main class

```
main.py

def cli(cmd_arguments):
    ...

    
if __name__ == "__main__":
   ...
   cli(args)
```

And this is the test method

```
   test_main.py
            
   import unittest
   from argparse import Namespace
   import sys
            
   from project.src.main import cli
   sys.path.append('../src')
    
    class TestMainMethod(unittest.TestCase):
    
        def test_path_exception(self):
            with self.assertRaises(Exception):
                args = Namespace(method="abc", path='abcd')
                cli(args)
```

And I am trying to run this command `python -m unittest` from `project` directory but getting exception `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'project.src'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`project` is not a package. it is your project root.

1. add `__init__.py` to you src folder (if you don't already have).
2. use `from src.main import cli`.
3. Generally, you should avoid using `sys.path.append('../src')`. I am not sure why you need it.